# Как получить список всех элементов из Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase-database

Как получить список всех элементов из Firebase Database?

Этот способ в 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1' не работает

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference myRef;

FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

FirebaseListAdapter mAdapter;

private EditText ET_new_task;
private Button Btn_new_task;

ListView ListUserTasks;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_tasks);

    ListUserTasks = findViewById(R.id.discr_for_task);

    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this, String.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myRef.child(user.getUid()).child("Tasks")) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, String s, int position) {
            TextView text = v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            text.setText(s);
        }
    };
    ListUserTasks.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    Btn_new_task = findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    ET_new_task = findViewById(R.id.et_new_tasks);

    Btn_new_task.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myRef.child(user.getUid()).child("Tasks").push().setValue(ET_new_task.getText().toString());
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Собирается? Есть логи? в каком месте ломается?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Необходимо выполнить:

```
    myRef.getRoot().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Timber.d(childDataSnapshot.getKey() + " " + childDataSnapshot.getValue());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```